# Can't Open rails console on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> I can start the server with **rails s** but I can't access the console.
>   When I try to open console those lines I see.

`$ rails c`

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 17025

Traceback (most recent call last):
    50: from -e:1:in `<main>'
    49: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    48: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    47: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
    46: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    45: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
    44: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
    43: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
    42: from /home/hasantezcan/Documents/programing/ruby/checklist_project/Checklist/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    41: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    40: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    39: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    38: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    37: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    36: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
    35: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    34: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    33: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    32: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    31: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:70:in `find_by_namespace'
    30: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:79:in `lookup'
    29: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:79:in `each'
    28: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:80:in `block in lookup'
    27: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:80:in `each'
    26: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
    25: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    24: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    23: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    22: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    21: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    20: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
    19: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    18: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    17: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:4:in `<main>'
    16: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    15: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    14: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    13: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    12: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    11: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
    10: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     9: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
     8: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `<main>'
     7: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     6: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     5: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     4: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     3: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
     1: from /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require': libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-linux/readline.so (LoadError)
```

[my enviroment version](https://i.hizliresim.com/DYm5Gl.png)

> How can I fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a missing system dependency according to the following error

```
libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Which you need to install. If you are on Ubuntu you can install the following package: `libreadline7`

Comment: I am using manjaro and I try to find  this package our repo using tihs code

**pacman -Ss libreadline7**

but its not make any return. 

What  can I do now?

Comment: in manjaro you can find it with the name **readline** https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/readline/ , try to install it if not installed already then create a symlink with the name **libreadline.so.7** as the current readline version is 8

Comment: @HasanTezcan also check this https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26658#issuecomment-251644858

Comment: If this file **/home/hasantezcan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-linux/readline.so** is not exist then after installing the package try to create it using symlink or try to reinstall ruby

Comment: I reinstalled my environment and its working now. Thanks everyone for helping